# Can Chrome v.21 be used without freezing my Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Chrome throws many errors, and after a few minutes my Mac freezes. What can I do?

Here is the error message.

> `Unsure about the internals of CFAllocator but going to patch them anyway. If there is a crash inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, please report it at http://crbug.com/117476 . If there is a crash and it is NOT inside of CFAllocatorAllocate, it is NOT RELATED. DO NOT REPORT IT THERE but rather FILE A NEW BUG.`

```
 Google Chrome Helper[2839]: Failed to look up domain bootstrapper during domain extension: 0x44c
```

Chrome 21.0.1180.89 - no extension.

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome 21.0.1180.89 - no extension.

Comment: What kind of freeze is it? Spinning Beachball? Stuck mouse?

Comment: First spinning beachball, after a few sec - stuck mouse.

Comment: Another error: 
> Google Chrome Helper[969]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)

Comment: According to http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php - your version looks very close to a beta version and you might need to consult the developers to see if anyone else is even running that older version on Mountain Lion. You might find someone who still runs that old version, but you might try the newer builds and see if the problem is your computer or just that build of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Remove chrome completely and reinstall. You can use appdelete or appzapper or something like that to make sure you get rid of everything associated with the app.

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: Did you fully uninstall it?  I assume it may leave some user preferences lying around and they get reused when you reinstall it.  If the problem is in there somehow, that could be it.  Just a guess - I haven't used Chrome on a Mac yet.

Comment: Full reinstall.